# Are these missing libs causing my app to crash?

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

After adding some new features to my released ios ionic app I've been battling with random crashes and white screens for the last month. I'm ready to throw the towel in and remove the app from the app store and stop using ionic (which is a shame as I love it).

After pretty much a month of trying to debug, removing plugins, removing code, rebuild platform, searching stackoverflow etc etc I'm grasping at straws now.

Could anyone tell me, are these missing files in xcode (added by cordova plugins) an issue? I've found lots of conflicting reports. Could these be responsible for why my app almost constantly white screens on launch (although some times it works).

[image: missing]

I'm using xcode 7.2.1 and

- Cordova CLI: 6.0.0
- Gulp version: CLI version 3.9.0
- Gulp local: Local version 3.9.0
- Ionic Version: 1.1.1
- Ionic CLI Version: 1.7.14
- Ionic App Lib Version: 0.7.0
- ios-deploy version: 1.8.5
- ios-sim version: 5.0.6
- Cordova-ios 4.0.1

My app runs fine in browser, with no console errors. It also works fine on Android which leads me to this it's either a cordova-ios issue or an xcode/ios specific issue.

I did find this: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10530 but after pulling in the master branch of cordova-ios i still get the whitescreens on launch most of the time.

Surely someone has had these issues?

I'm using these plugins:

- "cordova-plugin-device",
- "cordova-plugin-console",
- "cordova-plugin-whitelist",
- "cordova-plugin-splashscreen",
- "cordova-plugin-statusbar",
- "ionic-plugin-keyboard",
- "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner",
- "cordova-plugin-crosswalk-webview",
- "cordova-plugin-google-analytics"

White screen and xcode console:

[image: white screen and xcode console]

Thanks

Comment: can you tell me what error you are getting

Comment: No error, app build fine but almost always white screens and crashes on device/simulator

Comment: try to debug by directly running from xCode

Comment: and why the three frame works are in red color?

Comment: Xcode console doesn't throw any errors. The red files are what I'm concerned about - it seems to be xcode 7 that does have dylibs by default. I'm unsure if this is an issue though...

Comment: It gives you errors when it crashes. Enable a breakpoint to see at what point it crashes as well. The red colored frames might not mean anything.

Comment: And post the errors here, because without logs of some kind we can't help.

Comment: I've added a screenshot of the simulator when it's white screened and xcode console - as you can see there are no errors. @sschale

Answer (score 0):

Try

Removing the frameworks in red and re-add the following

```
 libsqlite3.tbd
 libz.tbd
 libiconv.tbd
```

as in xcode 7.2.1

the 
`.dylib` extensions are replced `.tbd`

Comment: Tried this previously and once again now - same issue - white screen on load. Debugging ionic is a nightmare.

Comment: You have to debug it through xCode.

Comment: That's something I'm not familiar with, ionic give no information on. I don't know obj-c or swift which is why I'm using ionic.

Comment: When I run the app via Xcode there are no errors or exception

Answer (score 0):

This may not be a perfect solution for your issue but can help you in debug the error

Ionic iOS app can be debug in the safari , in the safari developer options you can check the console error for the application, many of the white screen issues are displayed in the safari console

in Safari, `Go preferences -> advanced -> Show Develop menu in menu bar. Once you've that, build and run in xcode and then in safari go Develop -> iPhone Simulator -> Your App Name`

More information regarding this can be found in this url:
http://phonegap-tips.com/articles/debugging-ios-phonegap-apps-with-safaris-web-inspector.html

Your app may not have iOS framework/Xcode related issue as if that was the issue the app will be crashed or some error/warning log should be display in the Xcode console

Another issue can be plugin loading, as i have recently faced some issue like plugin was working perfect in the Android but it is not working properly in iOS,  it was solved by initialize plugin after `deviceReady()` event of cordova is called, now it working fine in iOS

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I've tried that, but it doesn't work. I run the app in xocde on an ios simulator and open safari, go to develop and select the simulator but nothing is displayed. I've even tried `window.location.reload()` within the remote inspector console but the white screen stays. I think when it white screens it doesn't attach the remote debugger as the title of the `window says Web inspector - Simulator - myApp - (null)`. When the app does occasionally launch it doesn't have the `(null)`.

Comment: The plugins that I call directly, such as $cordovaSplashscreen and $cordovaGoogleAnalytics are both inside of ` $ionicPlatform.ready()` the other plugins (like barcode scanner) are attached to a click event inside of a controller. Is there another way to initialize them?

Comment: To confirm the app works fine in browser and in android. It's only ios that has the issue.

Comment: Yes, when the app launch properly it show the page in the debug like '`Web inspector - Simulator - myApp - index.html`' in my case, safari console remains blank even when you reload page from safari (`cmd + R`) ?, `$ionicPlatform.ready()` is the correct method to initialize the custom plugins  in the Ionic

Comment: when the app whitescreens, I can't even view the markup using the inspector. I'm currently rolling back ios to cordova ios 3.9.2 to see if that helps. Looks like they have release 4.1.0 a few days ago but I can't seem to add it using cordova platform add ios@4.1.0 :(

Comment: okay, hope that works, as i am currently working with cordova version 3.9.2 also

Comment: Seems to have worked, restarted app 10+ times and no crash!